# SQL - Breaking the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this below query from my legacy application, while executing this, it is taking too much time to respond. So I am planning to break this complicated query into multiple queries and do some of the operations in the application side i.e. newer application.

```
 WITH members    AS (       
    SELECT
    shift_group_code,
    shift_code,
    0 AS isCycle,
    CHAR(10) + CAST(shift_group_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
    FROM shift_grouping       
    WHERE workspace_code IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')       
    AND shift_group_code = 'WS+DEFAULT'       
UNION
ALL       
    SELECT
    H.shift_group_code,
    H.shift_code,
    CASE                  
        WHEN M.[path] LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) + '%'                  
        THEN 1                  
        ELSE 0              
    END AS isCycle,
    M.[path] + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
    FROM
    shift_grouping H       

    JOIN
    members M       
        ON H.shift_group_code = M.shift_code       
        AND M.shift_code       IN (SELECT
            code 
    FROM
        shift_group)       
    WHERE
    H.workspace_code       IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')       
    AND M.isCycle = 0)       

    SELECT
        *       
    FROM shift       
    WHERE
        workspace_code       IN (
            'default', 'test', 'test1'
        )       
        AND (
            code = 'WS+DEFAULT'            
            OR code IN (
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT shift_code                        
                FROM
                    members                         
                WHERE
                    isCycle = 0
            )
        )
```

I could able to break the first part before `UNION`

i.e.

```
SELECT shift_group_code, shift_code,
        0 AS isCycle,
        CHAR(10) + CAST(shift_group_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
FROM shift_grouping       
WHERE workspace_code       IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')       
AND shift_group_code = 'WS+DEFAULT'
```

But the second portion of the query

```
SELECT H.shift_group_code, H.shift_code,
        CASE                  
            WHEN M.[path] LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) + '%'                  
            THEN 1                  
            ELSE 0              
        END AS isCycle,
        M.[path] + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
 FROM shift_grouping H       
 JOIN members M 
 ON H.shift_group_code = M.shift_code       
 AND M.shift_code IN (SELECT code FROM shift_group)       
 WHERE H.workspace_code IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')
```

I couldn't able to break, because there is a `JOIN members M` statement which is not allowing me to break the SQL.

`members` is coming from `WITH members` statement at the beginning of the bigger query.

Or I couldn't able to understand how are they joining `members` with `shift_grouping`.

Can someone able to provide some assistance to break this query for me?

Comment: does not seem to be related to java

Comment: Query performance doesn't depend on the query *size*. Performance suffers when indexes are missing or the expressions used can't take advantage of indexes. For example, a `LIKE '%whatever%'` will be slow no matter what because it can't use indexes. It has to scan the entire table to find matches.

Comment: Processing in the application is a way to *harm* performance by the way, as the client can't take advantage of indexes or the server's RAM and multiple cores. To improve performance you'll have to understand what the query does and create the *proper* schema, indexes and query. For example, why is the query looking for `CHAR(10)` ?

Comment: Is this a recursive query perhaps? In that case breaking it up will prevent it from working. Client-side evaluation could end up being orders of magnitude slower. Using a `hierarchyid` to store hierachical paths on the other hand will improve performance a lot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we resolved this issue in client side, with much better performance. Understanding the query in depth helped

Answer (score 1):

Is difficult to optimize that query without more knowledge about your database schema, but it can help you to understand what it's doing.

I also replaced a couple of IN conditions to EXISTS, it will give you a quite better performance, but i don't think that will be enough

Members is a Common Table Expression (CTE) that defines a temporary result set, when it call itself is known as a Recursive CTE.

SHIFT_GROUPING seems to be your Hierarchy table so, the first SELECT statement defines where the CTE starts, the SELECT after the UNION ALL defines the iterations

In general, a recursive CTE has three parts:

1. An initial query that returns the base result set of the CTE. The
   initial query is called an anchor member.
2. A recursive query that
   references the common table expression, therefore, it is called the
   recursive member. The recursive member is union-ed with the anchor
   member using the UNION ALL operator.
3. A termination condition
   specified in the recursive member that terminates the execution of
   the recursive member.

The execution order of a recursive CTE is as follows:

- First, execute the anchor member to form the base result set (R0), use this result for the next iteration.
- Second, execute the recursive member with the input result set from the previous iteration (Ri-1) and return a sub-result set (Ri) until the termination condition is met.
- Third, combine all result sets R0, R1, … Rn using UNION ALL operator to produce the final result set.

  ```
   ;WITH members    AS --CTE Declaration    
   (   
      -- Defines the initial query of the CTE
       SELECT
       shift_group_code,
       shift_code,
       0 AS isCycle,
       CHAR(10) + CAST(shift_group_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
       FROM shift_grouping       
       WHERE workspace_code IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')       
       AND shift_group_code = 'WS+DEFAULT'       

      UNION ALL       

      -- Recursive query that references [members]
      SELECT
       H.shift_group_code,
       H.shift_code,
       CASE                  
           WHEN M.[path] LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) + '%'                  
           THEN 1                  
           ELSE 0              
       END AS isCycle,
       M.[path] + CAST(H.shift_code AS varchar(max)) + CHAR(10) AS [path]       
       FROM
       shift_grouping H       
       JOIN
       members M ON H.shift_group_code = M.shift_code  -- In this case, the join acts as the termination condition           
       WHERE 
      H.workspace_code IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')  
      AND M.isCycle = 0
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shift_group WHERE code = M.shift_code)    
   )    
   SELECT *       
   FROM shift S    
   WHERE 
      workspace_code IN ('default', 'test', 'test1')   
      AND ( 
          code = 'WS+DEFAULT' 
          OR EXISTS (
                   SELECT 1                    
                   FROM
                       members                         
                   WHERE
                       isCycle = 0 AND shift_code = S.code
           )
       )
  ```